# floatingActionButton shows but figure is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello This is my code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed:(){
    Icon(Icons.edit);
  } ,),
```

The problem is, when i add any icon (like icons.edit or icons.alarm etc.), it shows empty circular button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
     //do something
   },
   child: Icon(Icons.edit),
),
```

This is because you are putting the Icon inside on onPressed. OnPressed is code that executes when the button is pressed, add a child Icon widget.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added a child to the `FloatingActionButton`.

Specify the `child` property of `FloatingActionButton`

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
  onPressed:(){
    // onPressed function
  },
),
```

Comment: Thank you for your helping.:)